# How to typescript file creating using with interfaces method other typescript file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, permissions

**I'm working on react native project with using typescript. Especially create a permission file with using link [this](https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions/blob/master/Example/Example.js)**

I have a camera and storage method basically and little bit confusing about how to create interface module on my project

```
const Permission = require('react-native-permissions')
import React from 'react'
import {
StyleSheet,
TouchableHighlight,
Text,
View,
Alert,
AppState,
Platform,
} from 'react-native'

interface Props extends {
string: []
}

interface PermissionsState extends {
status: {},
}

class Permissions extends React.Component<Props,PermissionsState> {
constructor(props) {
Permission.check([type])
type PermissionStatus = 'granted' | 'denied' |'never_ask_again';



this.state = {

};
}

render () {
return (
render() {
return (
<View>
<View/>
)
  }
}





 export default new Permissions()
```

and my errors begin `interface Props extends {` line and error description is:

An interface can only extend an identifier/qualified-name with optional type arguments.
(property) string: undefined[]

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to remove `extends` keyword from the declaration of your both interfaces. As they are not actually extending anything and react itself does not require them to implement/extend any other interface/class.

So your code can look something like this:

```
const Permission = require('react-native-permissions');
import React from 'react';
import {
        StyleSheet,
        TouchableHighlight,
        Text,
        View,
        Alert,
        AppState,
        Platform,
    } from 'react-native';

interface Props
{
    names: string[];
}

type PermissionStatus = 'granted' | 'denied' |'never_ask_again';

class PermissionsState
{
    public status: PermissionStatus;
}

export class Permissions extends React.Component<Props, PermissionsState>
{
    constructor(props: Props, context: any)
    {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = new PermissionsState();
    }

    public render()
    {
        return(<View/>);
    }
}
```

Comment: some errors about begin this line ;                                                     export class permissions ....                                                                               error's name is :                                                                                          Class 'permissions' incorrectly extends base class 'Component<Props, PermissionsState>'.
  Types of property 'render' are incompatible.
    Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type '() => false | Element'.
      Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false | Element'.

Comment: Make sure you declare your code in file with `tsx` extension. Not `ts`.

Comment: I have other file in ts format ,which file is I used interface module and it's working smoothly.

Comment: but changed file format tsx not problem but error is still module .

Comment: If you want to use jsx/tsx syntax sugar like `<View/>` you must use tsx

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by: "error is still module"

Comment: My problem is not <View/> in this time.This line above ;                               this.state = new PermissionState();                                                                my error is [ts] Cannot find name 'PermissionState'.
any
and my format is tsx at now changing your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry - my bad. It should be `PermissionsState` see updated code. Also note - I have changed `PermissionsState` to be class instead - so we can call `new`

Comment: Can I create  a  new class ? I confusing little bit .

Comment: Yes you can. You can also leave it to be interface and use `this.state = {};` instead. Class can be usefull if you want to have some initialization logic to be put in constructor

Comment: I just trying this situation about this command is like ;                                          this.PermissionsState = this.PermissionsState(this)                                      is it correctly using for this.state ?                                                                 if it's true usage ?

Comment: At now I fix my errors without new class ,and now I have need  a function for getting my camera and gallery module eg. set function